# Prepending zeros to a list

Tags: python, list, prepend

The story is as follows. The user inputs a number. Python converts the string into an int, and uses an algorithm to make a binary number. For example:

```
firstdecimal=input("Please enter your first denary number: ")

> 45

StrToInt = int(firstdecimal)
InputInt = ToBin(StrToInt)     # a working binary conversion function
print(InputInt)

> [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

What I need is that the function `Addzero(x)` is able to take the binary number list (`InputInt`), and add `0`s to the start. If there are already `8` elements in the list, then it does not need to add a `0`.

```
def Addzero(value):
    reverse = value[::-1] 
    if len(value) != 8:
        value.extend([0])
        if len(value) == 8:
            reverse = value[::-1]
    elif len(value) == 8:
        return
```

I couldn't find the code that lets me add the elements to the start, so I just implemented a reverse feature to circumvent it.

When i print the content of this function I get...

```
> None
```

Which is evidently not the intended result. I need the output. (a full `8` element list composed of `0`'s, `1`'s)

Like This:

```
> [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: How are you calling Addzero() and where are you printing?

Comment: from the shell. it was just a test, that part works fine, the code for that is:

    def ToBin(x):
        if x == 0:
            return [0]
        bit = []
        while x:
            bit.append(x % 2)
            x >>= 1
        return bit[::-1]

Comment: you said don't find the code to add element to a list? a simple check the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) have the answer

Comment: If you want to follow PEP (a python advice for coding, well, sort of), write your function names uppercased in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that it returns `None` is simply because your `return` statement is lacking an expression:

```
elif len(value) == 8:
    return
```

Therefore `return` simply means: "*We're done, stop executing this function, nothing should be returned*".

and furthermore not all code paths will do a return statement anyway. Finally your `AddZero` seems to add only a *single* zero, which can be inefficient.

A better solution is probably:

```
def Addzero(value):
    return [0] * max(0,8-len(value)) + value
```

Here the expression `[0]*n` means that you repeat `0` *n* times in a list. So `[0]*4` will result in `[0,0,0,0]`. Now the number of times we need to add this is `max(0,8-len(value))`. The `max(0,...)` is in fact not even necessary, so you can rewrite it as:

```
def Addzero(value):
    return [0] * (8-len(value)) + value
```

It means thus that the number of elements we have to short to generate an eight item list are constructed as a list of zero. And we add (append) with `+` the original list to it.

As @Later42 shows in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34245012/67579), you can make it more efficient, by doing a `len` check first, and in case it is equivalent to eight, return the list itself:

```
def Addzero(value):
    if(len(value) > 8) :
        return value
    else :
        return [0] * (8-len(value)) + value
```

**Demo** using Python's interactive shell:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Apr  2 2015, 15:33:21) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def Addzero(value):
...     return [0] * (8-len(value)) + value
... 
>>> Addzero([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

This might work? I have not tested it myself, but I think it should be fine.

```
def add_zero(binary_list):
    if len(binary_list) < 8:
        zeros = [0] * (8 - len(binary_list))
        return zeros + binary_list
    else:
        return binary_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions fit the bill I guess, but why not just use:

```
firstdecimal = input("Please enter your first denary number: ")

> 45

binaryStr = '{0:08b}'.format(firstdecimal)  # string, not a list

print(binaryStr)
> '00101101'

print(list(map(int, binaryStr))  # gives you the list
> [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Note that `08b` in the format string denotes that the argument `firstdecimal` is to be converted to a zero-padded 8-length binary string.

Comment: No real answer, more like a longer comment.